# How to use vuetify 3 data-table v-slot functionalities inside a custom component?

Tags: vue.js, datatable, components, vuetify.js, parent-child

I want to get v-data-table items and headers using slots from my custom component.

Custom Component: @/components/MyDataTable.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items"> </v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
    headers: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <my-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" item-value="name">
        <template v-slot:[`column.name`]="{ column }">
          {{ column }}
        </template>
        <template v-slot:[`item.name`]="{ item }">
          {{ item.props }}
        </template>
      </my-data-table>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import MyDataTable from "@/components/MyDataTable.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    MyDataTable,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        { title: "Dessert", align: "start", key: "name" },
        { title: "Calories", align: "end", key: "calories" },
        { title: "Fat (g)", align: "end", key: "fat" },
      ],
      items: [
        {
          name: "Frozen Yogurt",
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
        },
        {
          name: "Jelly bean",
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

If I put them in the native component they work, but if I put them in my own they do not work.

Expected Result:
[image]

Active Result:
[image]

I use vue 3 with vuetify 3.

Here is the [codesandbox ready link](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/olomadev/testvuetify/main?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FMyDataTable.vue&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522clf58w81k0007g3ivgaju5hve%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FMyDataTable.vue%2522%252C%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.vue%2522%252C%2522%252Fsrc%252Fplugins%252Fvuetify.js%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522clf55mb3x00153n6lqr8yhx9a%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clf55mb3x00153n6lqr8yhx9a%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clf5az4yt001a3n6kic68lb3l%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Atrue%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clf58wd2t004w3n6k6wxjicy5%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clf58wc49002r3n6k4urlqh1q%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522clf55mb3x00153n6lqr8yhx9a%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522clf55mb3x00153n6lqr8yhx9a%2522%255D%252C%2522hideCodeEditor%2522%253Afalse%257D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to forward the slots from the v-datatable by iterating over them, then creating new ones that can be accessed in parent component :

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items"> 
   <template v-for="(_, scopedSlotName) in $scopedSlots" v-slot:[scopedSlotName]="slotData">
        <slot :name="scopedSlotName" v-bind="slotData" />
   </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Thanks it works for vue 2, for vue 3 version we need to change the $scopedSlots as $slots. [Migration Guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/slots-unification.html)

Comment: Update:  Sometimes scopedSlotName comes null so we need to check it with v-if="scopedSlotName"  
````<template v-for="(_, scopedSlotName) in $slots" v-slot:[scopedSlotName]="slotData">
        <slot v-if="scopedSlotName" :name="scopedSlotName" v-bind="slotData" />
      </template>````